# failed looping through array with two value pairs

Tags: javascript, arrays, list

I'm trying to loop through this array

```
const test = [(18, 20), (45, 2), (61, 12), (37, 6), (21, 21), (78, 9)];
```

but it's output looks like this

```
console.log(test); //[20, 2, 12, 6, 21, 9]
```

please let me know how to loop through this array correctly .

Comment: I think you mean "loop **through**."

Comment: Re looping through an array, see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript/9329476#9329476).

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't the looping (though you haven't shown any looping in your question). Your array starts out with just the values `20`, `2`, `12`, etc. in it. `(18, 20)` evaluates to `20`, because the comma operator evaluates its left-hand operand (`18`), throws that away, and evaluates its right-hand operand and takes that value as its result.

If you wanted an array of tuples, you wanted `[]`, not `()`, on the inner arrays:

```
const test = [[18, 20], [45, 2], [61, 12], [37, 6], [21, 21], [78, 9]];
```